# How to add text on a bubble chart with plotly

Tags: python, text, plotly, bubble-chart

I am doing a Bubble chart with python using plotly. I want to visualize word frequencies. So I have made two columns with 5 bubbles and I would like to write the word inside each bubble. My code is:

```
trace0 = go.Scatter(
x=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
mode='markers',
text=['plant', 'use', 'student', 'show', 'water'],  #words I want to show
textposition='top center',
marker=dict(
    size=norm,
color=['rgb(255, 144, 14)','rgb(255, 144, 14)','rgb(255, 144, 14)', 'rgb(255, 144, 14)',
           'rgb(255, 144, 14)'],

)

)

trace1 = go.Scatter(
x=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
y=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
mode='markers',
text=['use', 'water', 'diagram', 'show', 'plant'],   #words I want to show
textposition='top center',
marker=dict(
    size=norm,
color=['rgb(93, 164, 214)','rgb(93, 164, 214)','rgb(93, 164, 214)','rgb(93, 164, 214)','rgb(93, 164, 214)'],

)
)

data = [trace0,trace1]
py.iplot(data, filename='bubblechart-size', layout=layout)
```

The problem is that no word is showed here. How to change the code to visualize them?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

I toook the example from this website [Text and Annotations in Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/)

I believe your 'mode' parameter is not accurate.

```
trace2 = go.Scatter(
                   x=[0, 1, 2],
                   y=[2, 2, 2],
                   mode='markers+text',
                   name='Markers and Text',
                   text=['Text D', 'Text E', 'Text F'],
                   textposition='bottom center'
                   )
```

So you should write in the mode parameter: **mode='markers+text'**